# How to publish Asp.net Core with React.js Solution on IIS

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core-3.1

I've created a solution with asp.net core with react.js template in visual studio 2022.

in above screen shot you can see the structure of my solution where both React.js and Asp.net Core projects are standalone. I'm consuming Asp.net Core api into my React.js project and I want to deploy my solution over IIS, but I don't know how I can publish this solution? Which project to publish?  if somebody knows please help me out.

Comment: Is this for a production application, or just for your own use?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup, but mine is a Blazor server app calling .net APIs.  You have to publish both projects separately, not the entire solution.